# How to solve this second order- non-linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm  trying to learn how to solve different forms of ODE, for instance this equation:

$$ \sigma’’ e^{2\sigma} + \sigma’^2 ( \sigma^{2\sigma} -2 ) =0,$$

where $\sigma’ = \frac{d\sigma}{dx}$. Any help to know whether  my solution is correct or not and how to make a consistent substitution in the last step?

**Here is my trail:**

let $\sigma= log ~r \to e^\sigma =r \to e^{2\sigma} =r^2, $ then

$ \sigma’ = \frac{r’}{r}, ~~~ \sigma’’ = \frac{r’’}{r}- \frac{r’^2}{r^2}$, substitute in the original equation, we get:

$$ 
r’’ r - 2 \frac{r’^2}{r^2} =0, 
$$
or,
$$ 
r’’ = 2 \frac{r’^2}{r^3}, ~~~~~~ (1) 
$$
now let $\upsilon= \frac{dr}{dx} =r’ ~~ \to ~ r’’ = \frac{d\upsilon}{dx}=  \frac{d\upsilon}{d r}  \frac{d r}{dx}= \upsilon   \frac{d\upsilon}{d r} $. Sub. in (1):

$$
\upsilon   \frac{d\upsilon}{d r}= 2 \frac{\upsilon^2}{r^3},
$$

separate variables to integrate

$$
\int \upsilon^{-1} ~ d\upsilon = 2\int r^{-3} ~ dr,
$$

$$
log ~ \upsilon = - \frac{1}{r^2}  ~~ \to ~ \upsilon = e^{-1/r^2},
$$

solve again for r, we get : $ \frac{dr}{dx} = e^{-1/r^2}$. Separate variables and integrate

$$e^{1/r^2} ~ dr= dx ~~~~ (2) $$

In this step we know that $\int e^u du = e^u$, so let

$ \frac{1}{r^2} = u ~~ \to -2 r^{-3} dr= du $, and sub. in (2)

$$
-\frac{1}{2} r^3 \int e^u du = \int dx ~~ \to ~ -\frac{1}{2} r^3 e^{1/r^2} = x. 
$$
Finally, remember from the first relations that $e^{-2\sigma}= r^{-2}, $ now are all those steps right? and I think I'm stuck in the last step, that how consistently sub. by $\sigma$ in

$$  -\frac{1}{2} r^3 e^{r^{-2}} = x $$

So any help in the last step, I wonder shouldn't substitute by $\sigma=log r$ from the beginning?

I will be so thankful to follow my solution!

Comment: As in the previous version of the question [(deleted)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4264286/how-to-solve-this-second-order-non-linear-ode), is that last factor really $(σ^{2σ}−2)$ or, as you use it, $(e^{2σ}−2)$?

Comment: No, your last integration is wrong, $r$ is not a constant relative to $u$, indeed as you defined shortly before, these variables are connected by $u=\frac1{r^2}$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann, hello, I don't get what do you mean in the first comment.

Comment: @LutzLehmann, in the second comment, do you mean Equ. 2? So what's the right way to make such integration $e^{1/r^2} dr=dx$?

Comment: I do not find the $σ^{2σ}$ term represented in the calculations afterwards. And not every integral can be symbolically solved.

Comment: @Dr.phy: You've been asked in this post and in its previous incarnation if the term $\sigma^{2\sigma}$ in your original equation is correct. Oddly ignored, but somehow the change to $e^{2\sigma}$ is intuited in the accepted answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$e^{2y}y''+y'^2(e^{2y}-2)y=0\implies y''+y'^2(1-2e^{-2y})=0$$
Take $y'=p$ and $ y''=p\frac{dp}{dy}$, then
the ODE becomes
$$\frac{dp}{p}=(2e^{-2y}-1)dy$$
Integrating both sides we get
$$\ln p=-(e^{-2y}+y)+A$$
$$p=Be^{e^{-2y}+y} \implies \frac{dy}{dx}=B e^{e^{-2y}+y} \implies B\int e^{y}e^{e^{-2y}} dy =x+C$$
Let $e^{-y}=t$, then we get the final solution as
$$\text{Erf}(e^{-y})=Dx+E.$$
$D$ and $E$ are constants of integration and $\text{Erf}(z)$ is the  error function.

Edit: $$\int_{0}^{y} e^y e^{e^{-2y}} dy =\int_{0}^{z} e^{-t^2} dt=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\text{Erf}(z)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\text{Erf}(e^{-y})$$

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. The problem I have an integral as that $ \int e^{-2y} dx$. Now by knowing $Ei(e^{-2y} )= x $ (let D=1 and E=0), do you know how to make such integration?

Comment: Sorry please see my edit where instead of $Ei$ we get error function.